# Firebase Push Notification Limitations

Tags: android, ios, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending Firebase Push notification with a Laravel package (https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) it is working fine on sending notification on a topic, but the issue is:

- I have 90k active devices as of play console stats show but when i send a push notification i only see 30k "Send" not 90k "Send" Why?
- My Second Question is there is firebase limitation explained on their website like if we send a push notification to a topic, like if there is any limit, any device restriction , device should be active / not active. If the device is not active then how did the non active receive the message ? What is the discard time when firebase stops sending to devices.

Can anyone help me understand this issue? Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Firebase Starter (free) pack.